Automatic transfer of one master google sheet to a shared google sheet to a student
I am a teacher. I have a google sheet gradebook. I am wanting to input grades into my master spreadsheet with tabs for each individual student. I would like to transfer each individual students gradebook to their own google spreadsheet. Where they can see it and what updates on it each week, but they do not have ability to edit it. However, I need all formting to transfer, as well. Is this doable?
I tried to use the "=importrange" function. It will either give me an error message and will not copy the data over, or it will copy the data without the formating and does not update when I input numbers into the master spreadsheet.

Automatic transfer of one master google sheet to a shared google sheet to a student
Formula used:
=IMPORTRANGE("urlofMasterSheet", "SheetName!A:Z")
Step by step process:

Choose the sheet name you want to share for that particular student. For Example "John Doe Grade"

Copy the full url of that sheet name.

Create the new spreadsheet that you want to share to your student. For Example "John Doe Grades"

In the new spreadsheet that was created enter this formula =IMPORTRANGE("URLfromMasterSheet," "SheetName!A:Z")

In the new SpreadSheet click share and input your student email address.


Sample Output:
Master Sheet

Student Sheet

Reference:
IMPORTRANGE
